# Spock Test to Check that a Java Program has Indeed Extracted a Specific File Extension

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, groovy, spock

I wrote the following program that successfully extracts a .json file. I want to check with Spock and Groovy that my method, indeed extracts a file with the .json extension. At the end of the question you can see the stack trace. I am completely new to testing and I am definitely missing the picture here as I am little bit confused. Any advice that you can provide me?

**TEST CLASS SO FAR**

```
    def "Json file is returned"(){
        given:
        JsonFile jsonFile = new JsonFile()
        String filename = "items.json"

        when:
        jsonFile.writingTheFile()
        String str = ""
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("./items.json"))
        writer.write(str)

        then:
        str == filename
    }
```

**CLASS TO TESTED**

```
package inventory;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class JsonFile extends TrackingFile {

    public JsonFile(ArrayList<Item> items) {
        super(items);
    }

    static String json = "";
    static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization().serializeNulls().setPrettyPrinting()
            .setVersion(1.0).create();

    @Override
    void createTheFile() {
        json = gson.toJson(super.items);
        System.out.println(json);

    }

    @Override
    void writingTheFile() throws IOException {
        String str = json;
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("./items.json"));
        writer.write(str);
        writer.close();

    }

}
```

**ABSTRACT CLASS THAT GETS EXTENDED TO THE TESTED CLASS**

```
package inventory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public abstract class TrackingFile {

    protected ArrayList<Item> items;

    public TrackingFile(ArrayList<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    abstract void createTheFile() throws IOException;

    abstract void writingTheFile() throws IOException;

}
```

I am receiving the following stack trace:
[image: Stack Trace Picture]

Comment: Checking that an actual file is written, constitutes an integration test. While maybe you want this in addition to (but not instead of) a unit test, if it is the only way to verify the correctness of your code, it is a symptom of bad code design: `writingTheFile` does not use a configurable `Writer` instance (via method parameter or setter for an instance field), but instead a constructor call hidden inside the method. I.e., the method is creating its own dependency, making it hard to test. You should refactor, then you can simply inject a mock writer, avoiding disk I/O in the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to get going with, I didn't know what your Item class was so substituted for String in this example.

You might want to make the path configurable so you can write to different places in tests etc, you also might want to check if the file already exists at the start of the test and remove it and/or remove it at the end of the test.

```
def "Json file is returned"(){
    given:
        JsonFile jsonFile = new JsonFile(['one', 'two'])
    when:
        jsonFile.createTheFile()
        jsonFile.writingTheFile()
    then:
        Files.exists(Paths.get("items.json"))
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answer, the test just passed. Something last I want to ask you. At the part of `new JsonFile(['one', 'two'])`, the IntelliJ marks it with yellow. When I am hovering above it it says **Constructor 'JsonFile' in 'inventory.JsonFile' cannot be applied to '([java.lang.String, java.lang.String])'** and as solution **Cast 1st Parameter as ArrayList<Item>**. Why is this happening? The test passes even if I change your approach to `new JsonFile(['one', 'two'] as ArrayList<Item>)`.

Comment: It's because the JsonFile constructor accepts a list of ArrayList<Item> rather than ArrayList<String>. You didn't include an import statement or class structure for Item so I substituted for String. You should change your code to pass in a list of Item to the JsonFile constructor.